# Server option is not available in downloaded package of Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have installed Eclipse from this link : https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and now I am trying to add Tomcat server but unable to find any option in my Eclipse IDE. Please find the attached screenshots for the reference.

I have downloaded the zip file of Apache Tomcat server from this link https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi and extract it under my work drive.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Had you downloaded Eclipse Java EE version?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should download this version:

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2018-09/r/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find **Server** option in your eclipse when you click on `Window > Show View`, you may have to install this plugin **Eclipse JST Server Adapters (Apache Tomcat, JOnAS...)**

You can click on **Help menu** in eclipse, then select **Eclipse Marketplace** and then search for text **server adapters** and it will list **Eclipse JST Server Adapters (Apache Tomcat, JOnAS...)** then just click on install and after it gets installed, restart eclipse.

Now browse again by clicking Windows menu and select `Open View > Others`, then it will start showing you server option.

Let me know if you face any trouble doing this.